# over writing in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

Guys I am using Spyder ide, but when I go to modify a certain thing in any line it selects the letter and starts typing above it and deletes the already written code rather than spacing and typing, any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to hit the [Insert key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_key) on your keyboard first and see if it toggles between the *Insert mode* and the *Overtype mode*:

> - **overtype mode**, in which the cursor, when typing, overwrites any text that is present in the current location; and
> - **insert mode**, where the cursor inserts a character at its current position, forcing all characters past it one position further.
>
> The insert/overtype mode toggling is not global for the computer or
> even for a single application but rather local to the text input
> window in which the Insert key was pressed.